# Como consumir uma API "sem permissão"

Tags: angular, api, rest, cors

Nas pesquisas que fiz, descobri que não é possível consumir uma API se não liberar o seu host no servidor(back-end), mas eu espero está enganado, este é o motivo desta pergunta, há algum método para consumir uma API "sem permissão"?

Meu problema é o seguinte, quero pesquisar o status de uma marca no INPI, pesquisei e não encontrei nenhuma API.

Este é o [link](https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/marcas/Pesquisa_classe_basica.jsp) onde é possível fazer a pesquisa.

O INPI se associou a [European Trade Mark and Design Network](https://www.tmdn.org/) e lá também é possível fazer esta [pesquisa](https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/welcome).

Utilizando o "Inspector" do navegador na aba network conseguir encontrar no site da European Trade Mark and Design Network a seguinte [url](https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/search-tmv?_search=false&nd=1540562034603&rows=10&page=1&sidx=tm&sord=asc&q=tmsort:%22test%22&fq=[]&pageSize=10&facetQueryType=2&providerList=null&expandedOffices=null&interfacelanguage=en&selectedRowRefNumber=null) na qual é retornado um json com o resultado que eu quero, porem ao tentar inserir esta url na minha aplicação a mesma apresenta o seguinte erro no console.

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same
>   Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em
>   https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/search-tmv?_search=false&nd=1540562034603&rows=10&page=1&sidx=tm&sord=asc&q=tmsort:%22test%22&fq=[]&pageSize=10&facetQueryType=2&providerList=null&expandedOffices=null&interfacelanguage=en&selectedRowRefNumber=null.
>   (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está
>   presente).[Learn More]
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/search-tmv?_search=false&nd=1540562034603&rows=10&page=1&sidx=tm&sord=asc&q=tmsort:%22test%22&fq=[]&pageSize=10&facetQueryType=2&providerList=null&expandedOffices=null&interfacelanguage=en&selectedRowRefNumber=null.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]

Já encontrei a seguinte "solução"

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Desta forma o Google Chrome é inicializado porém ignorando o "web security" e permitindo o CORS, mas o usuário não vai fazer isso para acessar a minha aplicação.

Todos os meus teste foram locais, estou utilizando o Angular 6.1.5, este é o trecho de código no qual estou tentando buscar a informação, acredito que não precise, mas se necessário posto o código completo.

```
return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then((resposta: any) => {
        console.log(resposta);
        return resposta;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 5):

Não, você não pode fazer uma solicitação direto do seu domínio, essa proteção existe para barrar sites de utilizarem recursos de outros domínios como se fossem seus.
Você pode no entanto enviar uma solicitação para o seu servidor, então do seu servidor enviar uma solicitação para INPI, dessa maneira evitando que o browser barre a solicitação por ser cross-origin.

Comment: Mas como faria esta solicitação?